# On verses, from major Hindu texts, similar in purport to those found in the Bhagawat Gita

Tags: scripture, krishna, bhagavad-gita, vyasa, manu-smriti

The [Mahabharatha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahabharata), which is one of the two "Itihasa" texts among Hindu Scriptures,is a work by Sri Vyasa.

It also contains the "Bhagawat Gita"(BG), the discourse given by Lord Krishna to Arjuna during the onset of the battle of Kurukshetra.

Bhagawat Gita is quite popular among the users on this site and many answers cite its verses.Even the users,who say that "the Puranas are work of men",do not hesitate quoting from the BG,despite the fact ,that all major Puranas and the BG are works of the same Sri Vyasa.

The following is one such [famous](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-3-35/) verse which says:
**1)**

> śreyān sva-dharmo viguṇaḥ para-dharmāt sv-anuṣṭhitāt sva-dharme
>   nidhanaḿ śreyaḥ para-dharmo bhayāvahaḥ

Meaning-

> It is far better to discharge one’s prescribed duties, even though
>   faultily, than another’s duties perfectly. Destruction in the course
>   of performing one’s own duty is better than engaging in another’s
>   duties, for to follow another’s path is dangerous.

**2)**

And the core message or one of Gita's essence is the doctrine of "Nishkama Karma".That is doing karma without having attachments to the fruits(Karmaphala).

This kind of karma is considered the best among all kinds and is said to grant liberation(moksha).

Question-Are there  verses in other major Hindu texts(like Srutis,Puranas,Smritis etc)  similar in purport with the verses& messages given above?

Comment: May be related [Is Bhagavad Gita text Shruti or Smriti?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8959/3500).

Comment: How can bHagwat Gita be Sruti????

Comment: Hindu Shatras clearly differentiates between Sruti(vEdas,),Vedangas(like Kalpa etc) Smritis ,Puranas and Itihasas .Among all these Vedas (sruti) are of the highest authority.all the remaining are having secondary importances only.But they are all important none the less.

Comment: @TheDestroyer More related to my this post is a@Tezz's post that talks about similar verses from the Devi mahatyam & the BG.

Comment: @Rickross -  Exactly same question as mine but asking verses from Upanishdas & Vedas :)http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15027/karmanye-vadhikaraste-ma-phaleshu-kadachana-similar-shlokas-from-vedas-and-upa

Comment: @SwiftPushkar You can give answers based on any shastras not necessarily from the Puranas.

Comment: Reason for the downvote???

Comment: I cannot understand why this question is down voted?

Comment: Yes that's y i asked..may be i hurt someone's biases,prejudices or something else..or may be someone has a valid reason..lets wait if that user replies back..haha..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bhagavata Purana talks about following one's own Dharma in [SB 3.28.2](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/28/2).

> sva-dharmācaraṇaṁ śaktyā
>
> vidharmāc ca nivartanam
>
> daivāl labdhena santoṣa
>
> ātmavic-caraṇārcanam
>
> One should execute his prescribed duties to the best of his ability and avoid performing duties not allotted to him. One should be satisfied with as much gain as he achieves by the grace of the Lord, and one should worship the lotus feet of a spiritual master.

Also, Nishkama Karma is described in [SB 11.3.46](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/3/46).

> vedoktam eva kurvāṇo
>
> niḥsaṅgo ’rpitam īśvare
>
> naiṣkarmyaṁ labhate siddhiṁ
>
> rocanārthā phala-śrutiḥ
>
> By executing without attachment the regulated activities prescribed in the Vedas, offering the results of such work to the Supreme Lord, one attains the perfection of freedom from the bondage of material work. The material fruitive results offered in the revealed scriptures are not the actual goal of Vedic knowledge, but are meant for stimulating the interest of the performer.

[Devi Bhagavata Purana, Ninth Book, Chapter XXIX](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk09ch29.htm) talks about both, following Sva-Dharma and Nishkama Karma.

> ये विप्रा अन्यदेवेज्याः स्वधर्मनिरताः सति । ते यांति सर्पलोकं च पुनरायांति भारते । 36 ॥
>
> हरिभक्ताश्च निष्कामाः स्वधर्मनिरता द्विजाः । ते यांति च हरेलॉक क्रमाद्रतिबलादही । 37 ॥
>
> स्वधर्मरहिता विप्रा देवान्यसेवनाः सदा । भ्रष्टाचाराश्व कामाश्च ते यांति नरकं ध्रुवम्। 38 ॥
>
> स्वधर्मनिरता एव वर्णाश्चत्वार एव च । भवंत्येव शुभस्यैव कर्मणः फलभोगिनः ॥ 39 ॥
>
> स्वकर्मरहिता ये च नरकं यांति ते ध्रुवम्। भारते न भवंत्येव कर्मणाः फलभोगिनः ॥ 4o ॥
>
> Those Brâhmanas that worship the other Devas and attached to their own Dharmas go to those regions of theirs respectively and again come to Bhârata. Attached to their own Dharmas, the Niskâmî Bhaktas of Hari go by their Bhakti step by step to the region of S’rî Hari. Those that are not attached to their own Dharmas and do not worship the Devas and always bent on doing things as they like without any regard to their Âchâras go certainly to hells. No doubt in this. The Brâhmanas and the other three Varnas, attached to their own Dharmas all enjoy the fruits of their good works. But those who do not do their Svadharma, go verily down into hells. They do not came to Bhârata for their rebirth, they enjoy their fruits of Karmas in hells!

Comment: @Rickross Thanks. Added original verses from Devi Bhagavatam now.

Comment: Devi bhagavatam is saying that lord Vishnu lord Shiva as karma while they have Karma how can they remove me from Karma
• Devi bhagavatam : 4 book : 2 chapter : 8-9 slokas 

• Devi bhagavatam : 6 book : 10 chapter : 15-18 slokas

Answer (score 7):

When Uddhava asked Shree Krishna about characteristics of men who are bounded ,free and who are devotees.Lord krishna given uddhava similar answers  as given to arjuna in Bhagvat Gita. We can find that conversation in **Shreemad Bhagvat Purana.**

> **इन्द्रियैरिनिन्द्रियार्थेषु गुणैरपि गुणेषु च । गृह्यमाणेष्व हं कुर्यान्न विद्वान यस्त्वविक्रिय:।।9।।**
>
> **Meaning** - Indriyas are like diseases of "Gunas" and material desires are also same. So with **Nirvikar or Nishkama** , a learned
>   men should understood that ,material desires is interaction between
>   various Indriyas.
>
> [**Shrimad Bhagvat Skanda / Adahya  11 , shloka 9**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/11/9)
>
> **यादनीशो धरायितुं मनो ब्रह्मणि निश्र्चलम । मयि सर्वाणि कर्माणि निरपेक्ष: समाचर।।22।।**
>
> **Meaning**-  If you are unable to concentrate your mind on me  , then do all your work as "Nirapeksha (निरपेक्ष) for me.
>
> [**Shrimad Bhagvat Skanda / Adahya  11 , shloka 22**](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/11/22)
>
> **निवृतं कर्म सेवेत प्रवृत्तं मत्परस्यजेत । जिज्ञासायाम  संप्रवृत्तो**
>   **नाद्रियेत कर्मचोदनाम।।4।।**
>
> **Meaning**-  A man who is devotee of Ishwara , should follow his daily duties.**Never to do "Sakam Karma"** ( or work with
>   expectations) . When  he will try to aquire "Atmagyan" (आत्मज्ञान or 
>   knowladge of self), then even he shouldn't care much about daily
>   duties also.This verse tells us about **"Pravrutta and Nivrutta karma"**
>
> [**Shrimad Bhagvat Skanda 11 / Adahya  10  , shloka 4**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/10/4)

Comment: @Rickross - Will add the similar shlokas from other texts in time for now have given the answer based on "Shreemad Bhagvat Purana"

Comment: Ok upvoted but do add replicas of the first verse in my question as well.

Comment: @Rickross - Thanks , i will also try and to add verses from that :)

Answer (score 5):

I am answering my own question based on the Manu Smriti ,the first of its kind among Hindu texts. Note that while the Mahabhratha depicts the events of the Dwapara Yuga, the Manu Smriti existed since Krita, the first among Yugas.

The following verse,is  saying exactly the same thing as  verse **1** given in the question:

> 10.97.*Varam swadharmo Viguno Na Paarakya Swanustitha|Paradharmena Jeevan hi Saddyah Patati Jaatitaha*- It is better (to discharge) one’s own (appointed) duty incompletely than to perform completely that of another; for he who
>   lives according to the law of another (caste) is instantly excluded
>   from his own.
>   [image]

The context above is of how the various duties are to be performed by the four varnas in times of distress(i.e when they are not being able to perform their respective prescribed duties properly).

And,the concept of "Nishkama Karma" is described in the next verses.The Manu Smriti talks about two kinds of karmas viz:**Pravritta** & 2)**Nivritta**(which is Nishkama Karma in BG).

> 12.88. The acts prescribed by the Veda are of two kinds, such as procure an increase of happiness and cause a continuation (of mundane
>   existence, pravritta), **and such as ensure supreme bliss and cause a
>   cessation (of mundane existence, nivritta**).
>
> 12.89. Acts which secure (the fulfilment of) wishes in this world or in the next are called pravritta (such as cause a continuation of
>   mundane existence); **but acts performed without any desire (for a
>   reward), preceded by (the acquisition) of (true) knowledge, are
>   declared to be nivritta (such as cause the cessation of mundane
>   existence).**

[image]

So,exactly the same message as given by Lord Krishna to Arjuna on the battlefield.

Expecting more answers from other users based on other texts like the Puranas etc.